How to show regular elements of compact simple Lie group G is dense in G?
I'm stuck in a sentence in  "Representations of Finite and Compact Groups (by Barry Simon)".
The sentence is

(every class of regular elements intersects the regular elements of $H$) and the regular elements are dense
(from p217)

$H$ is a maximal torus.
$x\in G$ is called regular if and only if $x$ lies in a unique maximal torus.
I asked another question about this textbook The number of regular elements in a maximal torus is the number of the elements of the Weyl group
and Mr. Callum taught me in the comment section that regular elements are dense in a semisimple Lie group. However, I can't ultimately come up with a way to prove it.
Does anyone have a good idea to prove it?

Wikipedia has some references for a proof ("For a connected compact Lie group ${\displaystyle G}$, the regular elements form an open dense subset, made up of  ${\displaystyle G}$-conjugacy classes of the elements in a maximal torus ${\displaystyle T}$ which are regular in  ${\displaystyle G}$").

Well technically what I said is that the set of regular elements is dense in a maximal torus although it does follow from this that the set of regular elements is dense in a connected compact group since in that case all elements lie in some maximal torus. I think it may be true in more generality although I don't know a proof. (I can find Corollary 5.4 in this for semisimple algebraic groups over algebraically closed fields and thus it is true for complex Lie groups)

@DietrichBurde Thanks for a good advice! I'll check it.

@Callum Thanks for coming giving comment again!!!
Would you know how to prove

the set of regular elements is dense in a connected compact group
? If yes, could you give some hints?


@DietrichBurde, Callum (sorry, i cant mention 2people at once)  Thanks, I found the proof about connected compact Lie group! I'll check it and be back!
